# parse error from R: after key and value, inside map, I expect ',' or '}' when reading json file

Tags: r, json, jsonparser

I am new to json file parsing, and have recently been trying to read a json file into R data table / data frame, but constantly getting error messages.

The json file in text looks like below:

```
{ " D " : " 1 - 2 - d r y . d e " , " S P " : 2 2 0 0 , " F I " : " 2 0 1 3 - 0 2 - 2 8 " , " L I " : " 2 0 2 0 - 0 4 - 2 8 " , " T " : [ { " N " : " H o s t E u r o p e   D N S " , " F D " : " 2 0 1 3 - 0 6 - 2 2 " , " L D " : " 2 0 1 8 - 0 4 - 0 8 " } , { " N " : " A p a c h e " , " F D " : " 2 0 1 3 - 0 5 - 3 0 " , " L D " : " 2 0 2 0 - 0 9 - 1 0 " } , { " N " : " P N G   F i x " , " F D " : " 2 0 1 3 - 0 5 - 3 0 " , " L D " : " 2 0 2 0 - 0 9 - 1 0 " } , { " N " : " H o s t   E u r o p e " , " F D " : " 2 0 1 3 - 0 5 - 3 0 " , " L D " : " 2 0 1 8 - 0 6 - 1 8 " } , { " N " : " S e r i f   W e b P l u s " , " F D " : " 2 0 1 3 - 0 2 - 2 8 " , " L D " : " 2 0 2 0 - 0 9 - 1 0 " } , { " N " : " n g i n x " , " F D " : " 2 0 1 4 - 0 6 - 1 1 " , " L D " : " 2 0 1 5 - 0 6 - 1 9 " } , { " N " : " I P v 6 " , " F D " : " 2 0 1 4 - 0 6 - 1 1 " , " L D " : " 2 0 2 0 - 0 9 - 1 0 " } , { " N " : " A p a c h e   2 . 4 " , " F D " : " 2 0 1 8 - 0 9 - 1 2 " , " L D " : " 2 0 2 0 - 0 9 - 1 0 " } , { " N " : " C o p y r i g h t   Y e a r   2 0 1 1 " , " F D " : " 2 0 1 8 - 1 0 - 1 4 " , " L D " : " 2 0 2 0 - 0 5 - 1 3 " } , { " N " : " G o D a d d y " , " F D " : " 2 0 1 9 - 0 7 - 1 1 " , " L D " : " 2 0 2 0 - 0 9 - 1 0 " } , { " N " : " C o m m o n   N a m e   I n v a l i d " , " F D " : " 2 0 1 9 - 1 1 - 1 8 " , " L D " : " 2 0 2 0 - 0 5 - 1 3 " } , { " N " : " I m p r e s s u m " , " F D " : " 2 0 2 0 - 0 4 - 2 8 " , " L D " : " 2 0 2 0 - 0 9 - 1 0 " } ] } 
 { " D " : " 3 - d - f o t o . d e " , " S P " : 5 4 3 , " F I " : " 2 0 1 5 - 0 1 - 2 7 " , " L I " : " 2 0 1 9 - 1 1 - 1 9 " , " T " : [ { " N " : " A p a c h e " , " F D " : " 2 0 1 5 - 0 1 - 2 7 " , " L D " : " 2 0 2 0 - 0 9 - 1 0 " } , { " N " : " P N G   F i x " , " F D " : " 2 0 1 5 - 0 1 - 2 7 " , " L D " : " 2 0 2 0 - 0 9 - 1 0 " } , { " N " : " S e r i f   W e b P l u s " , " F D " : " 2 0 1 5 - 0 1 - 2 7 " , " L D " : " 2 0 2 0 - 0 9 - 1 0 " } , { " N " : " H o s t E u r o p e   D N S " , " F D " : " 2 0 1 5 - 0 1 - 3 0 " , " L D " : " 2 0 2 0 - 0 9 - 1 0 " } , { " N " : " I P v 6 " , " F D " : " 2 0 1 5 - 0 2 - 0 6 " , " L D " : " 2 0 2 0 - 0 9 - 1 0 " } , { " N " : " H o s t   E u r o p e " , " F D " : " 2 0 1 5 - 0 1 - 3 0 " , " L D " : " 2 0 2 0 - 0 9 - 1 0 " } , { " N " : " G e r m a n " , " F D " : " 2 0 1 7 - 0 6 - 0 3 " , " L D " : " 2 0 2 0 - 0 9 - 1 0 " } , { " N " : " P o u n d   S t e r l i n g " , " F D " : " 2 0 1 8 - 0 9 - 1 7 " , " L D " : " 2 0 2 0 - 0 8 - 1 8 " } , { " N " : " G o D a d d y " , " F D " : " 2 0 1 9 - 0 7 - 1 1 " , " L D " : " 2 0 2 0 - 0 9 - 1 0 " } , { " N " : " C o m m o n   N a m e   I n v a l i d " , " F D " : " 2 0 1 9 - 1 1 - 1 9 " , " L D " : " 2 0 2 0 - 0 4 - 1 9 " } ] }
```

The code I used for read the json file is this:

```
json_file <- file("/...path/filename.json")
json_data <- fromJSON(json_file)
```

The error message looks like below:

```
Error in parse_con(txt, bigint_as_char) : 
  parse error: after key and value, inside map, I expect ',' or '}'
          - d r y . d e " , " S P " : 2 2 0 0 , " F I " : " 2 0 1 3 - 
                     (right here) ------^
```

I have also noticed that there is this whitespace between every letters or digits in the json file. Could anyone tell me what went wrong here and what I should do to read the json file?

Thanks a million!

Comment: That is because there is nothing like `2 2 0 0` in any computing language. Although there is `2200` or even `"2 2 0 0"`. Note that the first one has no space while the second is surrounded by the quotation marks

Comment: Somethings wrong with your JSON file. There should not be all those spaces in there. Where is it coming from? How did you get it onto your computer?

Answer (score 0):

Your file is probably in UTF-16 for some reason; the "whitespace" is null bytes. You might want to address that at the source, otherwise try the `encoding="UTF-16LE"` argument to `file`.